# ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together

Tags: xcode, swift, bitcode

I want to build my app **with** Bitcode enabled. As far as I know all my 3rd party library dependencies are Bitcode enabled. But when I do a build, I get this error:

`ld: -bundle and -bitcode_bundle (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE=YES) cannot be used together`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had erroneously set my `DEBUG` and `TEST` configurations to build with Bitcode, and this was what caused the above error. Enabling Bitcode only for `RELEASE` fixed it:

[image]

(Your App and any embedded framework targets should look like this—don't enable Bitcode at all on your test and UI testing targets.)

Comment: Setting "Enable Bitcode" to "No" for the Unit Test Build target solved it. Thanks!

Comment: I faced this error when launching on a device, although on Simulator this error does not appear

Comment: If you don't see `Enable Bitcode`, check that `BaseSDK` is correctly set to `iOS` (or whatever platform you're using).

Comment: Did you ever have this issue in release mode? I'm building OpenSSL 3 in release mode and get this exact problem. I need bitcode, though. What is the other one, `-bundle`?

Comment: I don’t recall, sorry. Bitcode is deprecated as of Xcode 14 though, so if you can wait long enough your problem will just go away .